# Does the generator of a finite field depend on the used irreducible polynomial?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let our finite field be $\operatorname{GF}(2^{8})$ with an irreducible polynomial: $$p_1=x^8+x^4+x^3 +x^2+1$$

I saw here [The Laws of Cryptography: Generate Multiplication Tables](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/laws/FFM.html) that $$\alpha=x+1$$ is a generator of $\operatorname{GF}(2^{8})$. But when I used this [finite field calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~algebra~calcff.en.html), the order of $\alpha$ was displayed as:

$$\operatorname{ord}(\alpha)=51$$

They used a different irreducible polynomial on their site ($p_2=x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$). So does the generator of a finite field depend on the used irreducible polynomial?

Is there something like an online calculator to find the generators over a finite field with a given irreducible polynomial?

**Update**

My Python 3 code to calculate roots and generators can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/winklerrr/524975ee6da4fd209834ab1cd66a228c). Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it does. For instance, the polynomials $x^4+x+1$ and its conjugate $x^4+x^3+1$ are irreducible over $GF(2)$ and  primitive, i.e., each zero $\alpha$ of them is a primitive generator of the multiplicative group of the field $GF(16)$.

On the other hand, the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$ but a divisor or $x^5-1$ and so not primitive, i.e., each zero $\alpha$ of it satisfies $\alpha^5=1$.

All in all, the polynomial $x^{16}-x$ factors as follows:
$$x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$

Comment: What do you mean by "zero $\alpha$"?

Comment: A zero is a root of a polynomial.

Comment: So do I need to check if $p(\alpha)=0$? So for instance take $p=x^4+x+1$ and $\alpha = x^2$ then $p(\alpha)=0$ is true? (Because $p$ has no term $x^2$?)

Comment: No if $p=x^4+x+1$ and $\alpha$ is a zero, then $p(\alpha)=\alpha^4+\alpha+1=0$ and so $\alpha^4=\alpha+1$ since we work over $GF(2)$.

Comment: Could you name me a zero $\alpha$ for my $p_1$?

Comment: It's a formal zero.

Comment: So I think I found a root $\alpha=x^4$ so that $p_1(\alpha)=0$ holds, thank you very much! (I found 8 roots at all, which seems logical because $\operatorname{dim}(p_1)=8$)